# Zend DB fetchAll() not working with "id" column with values over 926

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've been trying to retrieve some data using Zend DB fetchAll(), but the problem I'm facing is that I have a table that has around 475 rows, with an incremental ID starting at 755 and ending in 1230, but when I try to get data using

```php
$select = $db->select()->from('projects');
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

entries whose IDs are over 926 are not retrieved, I've though it was a memory issue so I tried to limit my query for only those above 926

```php
$select = $db->select()->from('projects')->where('id>926');
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But I got nothing, I even tried with just **1** id.

```php
$select = $db->select()->from('projects')->where('id=927');
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have data in your database with ID over 926?

Comment: Yes, I have IDs over 926.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below

```
$select = $db->select()->from('projects')->where('id = ?', 926);
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

or

```
$select = $db->select()->from('projects')->where('id > ?', 926 );
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It will also prevent SQL injection in your query.